# MS Excel: Count number of instances between commas

Tags: excel, count

In A1 I have a string of numbers that I want to be able to count the number of instances

A1: 1,14,19,23,52,1,16,14

In B1 I want to be able to count the instances of the number 1 in A1

Result: 2

I've been looking around but have been having issues with finding the unique values (i.e. looking exactly for 1 instead of counting all instances of 1)

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and the problems you have run into.

Comment: `=(LEN("," & A1 & ",")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("," & A1 & ",",",1,","")))/LEN(",1,")`

Comment: The equation Scott gave me was great. However, the cell has: 18,19,21,28,21,27,27 and when I throw in the equation it gives me a count of 1 when trying to count 27.

Comment: Is Scott's equation the only one you have tried?  Surely you must have tried one of your own before posting.

Comment: I changed the equation to work with doubles like that `=(LEN( A2 & ",")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2 & ",","27,","")))/LEN("27,")`

Comment: This works best `=(LEN( "," & SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",",,") & ",")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("," &  SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",",,") & ",",",1,","")))/LEN(",1,")`

Answer (score 0):

This works best

```
=(LEN( "," & SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",",,") & ",")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("," & SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",",,") & ",",",1,","")))/LEN(",1,")
```

By @Scott-craner